# How to create a global function in Xul?

Tags: javascript, xul

Is there a way of creating a global function in Xul (using javascript, I believed is the only way), such as I could call it from any file of any window?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to avoid including the same javascript file in each window?  Or are you okay with doing that, but want the scope to be shared across all windows like a singleton?

Comment: @pc1oad1etter I want to avoid including the same javascripts files in each window.

Comment: Not aware of anything like that, short of maybe building a custom xulrunner.  Javascript code modules give you global singletons, but that's not what you're after.

Comment: @pc1oad1etter Maybe I can use this global singletons, if they are accessible by any window.. Where can I read more about it?

Comment: Javascript code modules (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_JavaScript_code_modules);  You include them with a statement like this at the top of the files: Components.utils.import("resource://app/my_module.jsm");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a component and register it with the `JavaScript global privileged property` category then it will appear as a global object in every chrome window.

Comment: I've used XPCom to do it. The @pc1oad1etter and your answers are good too, thanks!